# Keycloak with api gateway Invalid bearer token

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to use Keycloak behind an API gateway (Apache APISIX).

I use minikube to run Keycloak and my API gateway.

The gateway is working right and Keycloak too :

With Keycloak, I can use the different end-point (use the discovery end-point (http://127.0.0.1:7070/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/uma2-configuration), ask an access token and verify it).

With APISIX, and a simple route, I can join a backend microservice on my minikube.
(typically : http://127.0.0.1:80/greeting is served by the gateway which routes the request to the right backend microservice)

The problem occurs when I try to use the two tools together. I have used the Keycloak integration, in order to force the user to use a valid token when he is using a route served by the gateway.

In this case, when I use a valid bearer token (I get it and verify it with the end-point of keycloak), and I try to request the backend via the api gateway with the verified bearer token, I obtain systematically an "Invalid bearer token" exception.

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid bearer token"}
```

I think the settings of the integration is well set because I am sure that te gateway call Keycloak to verify the token.

Here are the keycloak I have used to get and verify the token :

Get token : http://127.0.0.1:7070/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token

Verify : http://127.0.0.1:7070/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

I have seen some posts about problem when Keycloak is behind a reverse proxy, but I don't find a clear solution to my case.

Thanks for any help you can bring to me.
Regards
CG

Answer (score 0):

I think there are those ways you can do it.

First, I think you can check the log of `Apache APISIX`.

Second, you can check the log of `Keycloak`.

Third, you can use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to capture the request that Apache APISIX sends to keycloak.And diff the request that sends by APISIX and curl.

Looking forward to your reply.